# Cannot use Classes on this ref ClassName (byRef) method Feature C# 7.2

Tags: c#, c#-7.2

i was testin the new and shiny C# 7.1/7.2/7.3 features and when i was trying out the this ref Class, it was not working, meanwhile this ref int worked, do you guys have any idea on how to make it work with classes?

Example of the code:

```
    public static bool Works(this ref int i)
    {
        return i == 0;
    }

    public static bool DontWorks(this ref Test i)
    {
        return i.A == 0;
    }

    public class Test
    {
        public int A { get; set; }
    }
```

I am sorry that the title was a little bit bad, but i didnt know on how to make it better, feel free to give me suggestions or edit if you like.

Thank you for your time, and have a nice day.

Comment: Please paste the code into your question rather than using a screenshot. It helps people copy and paste your code to test it themselves.

Comment: Extension functions don't need `ref`

Comment: Why do you think you need `ref` here? Your code will work fine without it.

Comment: @GabrielLuci Edited the question thank you.

Comment: @Neil They do not? now i am confused, why would they add this feature then?

Comment: @PatrickHofman I heard that doing this is more efficient and prevents unnecessary copying of the data, and i am working with big classes with nested classes inside, so i wanted to make the code as efficient and performant as i can

Comment: `this ref` is available only for Value types.

Comment: What is _"Not Working"_ means, if you pay attention to compilation errors, you will see something like this - _"C# The first parameter of a 'ref' extension method 'DontWorks' must be a value type or a generic type constrained to struct."_.

Comment: @SeM Yeah i read that, but if you pay attention to my question, i asked how could i make it with classes, but it seems that classes already work with references.

Comment: @axd221 If compiler says _"'it must be a value type"_, then it **must** be value type, no exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ref extension methods are only allowed on types known to be structs. This is intentional. The reasons behind this can be found in the [feature proposal document](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/csharp-7.2/readonly-ref.md#refin-extension-methods).

Besides, regular class types are reference types. Passing a [reference type as a parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/passing-reference-type-parameters) does not copy the object, unlike [with value type parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/passing-value-type-parameters).

Comment: Thank you for explaining me and giving the material to read about, learned a lot reading the links you gave me.